# how to preserve folders and downloaded files of the app during uninstalling app

Tags: android

While Uninstalling my app all songs were deleted which were downloaded through that application.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are saving your files in your apps private external storage. It will be deleted when uninstalling your app. See: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteExternalStorage

Use

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

to get the primary external storage location and create a directory for e.g. your downloads and save them there.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()